# CEWP - Adding links to a File on File Share. But link wont open

Tags: hyperlink, file-server

I have a Wiki Page where I have a Content Editor Web Part. I have added a link to a file share. When I hover over the hyperlinked text I can see it's pointing to the correct location and file. But nothing happens when I click on it. It's like clicking on non-hyperlinked text.

I can right click and copy the link and paste in Windows Explorer and it resolves the path and file. Not sure what else can I do. IE is our only browser but I tested with Chrome and FF and they all are behaving the same manner.

I tried various format and none would work. here are some example what I have tried.

```
<a href="file://server/legal Purchasing/Procurement Active/2014/New procurement list as of 10012013.xlsx">Current procurement List</a>

<a href="file://\\server\legal Purchasing\Procurement Active\2014\New procurement list as of 10012013.xlsx">Current procurement List</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<a href="file://///server/legal Purchasing/Procurement Active/2014/New procurement list as of 10012013.xlsx">Current procurement List</a>
```

Comment: that did not work. Any other ideas.

Comment: hi jennifer, when you copy and past the link into the browser and press enter, wait for it to load.. than copy that url and use it in the href.... if in dout past the url here and ill update the answer! i might think it has todo with the spaces!